# How can I update the TextView in Fragment when I click in a button?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have a fragment with the respective code:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

public static Fragment1 newInstance() {
    Fragment1 fragment = new Fragment1();
    return fragment;
}

public Fragment1() {
    // Deve existir um construtor vazio
    // na classe que estende um Fragment
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment1, container, false);
}

public void changeText(){
    //this textview should be bound in the fragment onCreate as a member variable
    TextView frv= (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.msgStatusPorta);
    frv.setText("Porta Atualmente Aberta");

}
```

In my MainActivity, I do this:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager(); //if you added fragment via layout xml 
Fragment1 fragment = (Fragment1)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);
```

And in the onClick, I do

```
fragment.changeText(view);
```

I try to update my Textview from the method changeText() But when I click on the button and this method is called, my application crashes.Can someone help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: it's changeText(View v)

Comment: Where is `changeText` called from? You need to make sure it's in the onViewCreated or later to guarantee the view exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily by using interface. Do something like this in your activity

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    FragmentCommunicator fragmentCommunicator;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                fragmentCommunicator.changeText("Hello");

            }
        });

    }

    public void passVal(FragmentCommunicator fragmentCommunicator) {
        this.fragmentCommunicator = fragmentCommunicator;

    }

}

public interface FragmentCommunicator {
   public void changeText(String textVal);
}
```

And do something like this in your fragment.

```
@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup  container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment1, container, false)
    ((YourActivity) getActivity()).passVal(new FragmentCommunicator() {
        @Override
        public void changeText(String textVal) {  
               TextView frv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.msgStatusPorta);
               frv.setText(textVal);
           }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it woked very well.

Comment: if this answer works for you please accept or upvote to answer.

Answer (score 0):

have you put fragment through xml, then you can do this:

```
private MyFrag fragment; //MyFrag is your fragmemt
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    fragment = (MyFrag)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);

    Button yourbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourbutton);
    yourbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
      public void onClick(View view){
            fragment.setEditText("Your Text");
      });
```

In your fragment:

```
 public void setEditText(String text){
     edittext.setText(text);
 }
```

Comment: You didn't define `yourbutton`

Comment: thanks for pointing out. I'm editing it. meanwhile, I left it intentionally for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `onViewCreated()` in your fragment and initialize your `TextView` -

```
private TextView textView;
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

       textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.msgStatusPorta);
}
```

and change `changeText()` to -

```
public void changeText(){
    //this textview should be bound in the fragment onCreate as a member variable

    textView.setText("Porta Atualmente Aberta");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `onActivityCreated` method on your Fragment class, and then look-up the edit-text view. `onActivityCreated` method is called after the `onCreateView()` method when the host activity is created. `Activity` and `Fragment` instance have been created as well as the view hierarchy of the activity. At this point, view can be accessed with the `findViewById()` method.

```
private TextView frv;
private Button yourbutton;
...

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View rooView = getView();
  frv= (TextView)rooView.findViewById(R.id.msgStatusPorta);
  yourbutton = (Button)rooView.findViewById(R.id.your_button_res_id);
  ...
}
```